# Geolocalizacion en if

Tags: javascript, php

Realmente necesito esto :

Conseguir su ip , luego con su ip su geolocalización , luego con esto su pais y luego con esto lograr hacer un if

que el if quedara asi:

```
if(francia) {
//
}
```

se entiende?

En este caso solo quiero mostrar la bandera como en https://www.elhacker.net/geolocalizacion.html
osea en el if se mostraria una bandera de francia si es de francia su ip

Comment: "*se entiende?*". Pues sinceramente: No mucho. ¿Quieres usar la API de Google Maps? ¿quieres geolicalizar con alguna otra librería?

Comment: Quiero consegui su ip , para con esto conseguir su localizacion y su pais , sin mostrar nada , para que con todo esto al darme su pais , yo puedo hacer un if , tal como el que puse

Answer (score 0):

Acá te dejo una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip) de Stack Overflow versión en Inglés que espero que te sea de mucha ayuda.

Por petición de los comentarios voy a copiar la respuesta y te voy a dar un modo de uso:

Primero declaramos la función `ip_info()`:

```
<?php

function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

?>
```

Luego obtenemos la ip del cliente y la pasamos a la función de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    // Obtengo la IP del cliente
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip_del_cliente= $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip_del_cliente = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip_del_cliente = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    if (ip_info($ip_del_cliente, "Country") == "France") {
        // Hago algo
    }
?>
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda. Todo el crédito al autor de la respuesta original.

[Fuente para obtener la ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: Si pero necesito hacer un if con el pais , como lo haria ?

Comment: Ahí modifiqué el link a uno que se ajusta mas a tus necesidades

Comment: @EduardoCampos No esperes que se te hagan un ejercicio de clase aquí. Si no es un error específico, como mucho podremos darte alguna posible solución, no trabajar para hacerte el código.

Comment: Si no pones el código con la referencia entonces es mejor que lo conviertas en un comentario

Comment: @aldanux, querés que copie y pegue toda la respuesta del otro usuario?

Comment: Es totalmente legítimo mientras hagas referencia...

Comment: Hecho! Ahí edité la respuesta